# How to explicit import from submodule of a builtin

Tags: python

Working with Python for Foundry Modo 3D application, and their Python SDK `lx` is a builtin module.

```py
>>> type(lx)
"<class 'module'>"
```

`symbol` is a module in lx, which contains constants.

What I'm trying to do is run

```py
from lx.symbol import sCATEGORY_TOOL
```

But this raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lx.symbol'; lx is not a package`

It is all mostly to avoid having to type `lx.symbol.i_VERY_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME`

=== Edit ===

Ok, so it could be solved by doing

```py
import lx
foo = lx.symbol.foo
bar = lx.symbol.bar
baz = lx.symbol.baz
...
```

But I think it seem much more clear if it would come as

```py
from lx.symbol import foo,\
  bar,\
  baz,\
  ...
```

Comment: Can't you just `sCATEGORY_TOOL = lx.symbol.sCATEGORY_TOOL`?

Comment: Sure, but seems very tedious when you're dealing with 10+ constants you want imported from that module. 

Not to mention going to definition would take me to the top, then to the actual definition (well not actual definition as I'm going from generated stubs which I'm attempting to document better from header files...)

Comment: you said `symbols` but then you wrote `from lx.symbol` ... is it just a typo?

Comment: It's a typo yes, made edit to fix it

Comment: can you `import lx`?

Comment: Yes, you can `import lx` - but you will have to get constants like `lx.symbol.s_CATEGORY_TOOL` doing so

Comment: `from lx import symbol as s` ... `SHORTCONST = s.LONG_CONSTANT`

Comment: Just seem like the solution @YevhenKuzmovych gave but with extra steps, say I import 10+ constants. Quickly just becomes a huge block at the top of the file.

Comment: What's the problem with having 10+ constants at the top of the file?
Whatever method you use, it will require writing names of 10+ constants (or do you want to import all constants? - that's a bad practice anyway) and won't allow you to go to a definition of these constants (unless your IDE is VERY smart) as it's a built-in module.

Comment: To me it would look more clear having

``` python
from lx.symbol import foo,\
  bar,\
  baz
```

as opposed to

``` python
foo = lx.symbol.foo
bar = lx.symbol.bar
bax = lx.symbol.bax
```